# I have problems with my API CORS connection in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, cors

I can connect to my API locally but I cant with the one that is in heroku. I get the next error in may client console:

ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://murmuring-eyrie-8472278.herokuapp.com/auth/website-token' from origin 'https://wizardly-snyder-a0a62273.netlify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My code is this:

```
app.use( ( req, res, next ) => {    
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://wizardly-snyder- 
     a0a673.netlify.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Access- 
     Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,X-Requested-With,Content- 
     Type,Accept,content-type,application/json");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, 
     OPTIONS ")

  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Or I've used this too, but it did not work

```
app.use(cors( {
  credentials: 'true',  
  origin: '*', 
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS', 
  allowedHeaders: 'Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,X- 
     Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json'
} ));
```